# Unable to connect to self-hosted WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, windows-services

I am trying to build a fairly basic WCF SOAP web service self-hosted as a Windows service. The Windows service itself is up and running on my machine -- I just can't access it locally via Visual Studio or the web browser.

The relevant C# code is below. Assume `MyDummyService` implements contract `IDummyService`:

```
public class Program : ServiceBase
{
    private ServiceHost host = null;
    private readonly Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/DummyAPI");

    public static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(new Program());
    }

    public Program()
    {
        this.ServiceName = "DummyService";
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        log.Info("Starting service");

        try
        {
            base.OnStart(args);

            host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyDummyService), baseAddress);

            host.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (host != null)
                ((IDisposable)host).Dispose();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        log.Info("Stopping service");
        base.OnStop();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

The relevant `app.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="DummyAPI.MyDummyService" 
                 behaviorConfiguration="MyDummyBehavior">
           <endpoint 
               address="" 
               binding="basicHttpBinding" 
               contract="DummyAPI.IDummyService" />
           <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                     contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyDummyBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" policyVersion="Policy15"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

When I access

```
http://localhost:8000/DummyAPI
```

or

```
http://localhost:8000/DummyAPI/MyDummyService
```

(or either of those followed by ?wsdl) in the web browser, I get a 404. The obvious first question: what did I botch above?

The `web.config` namespaces (or what look like namespaces) have me a little confused. What can I safely make up on the spot, and what needs to reflect C# class namespaces?

Comment: There is a thing called tracing, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are disposing your ServiceHost in Start method which efectively leaves you without running ServiceHost.

```
finally
{
    if (host != null)
        ((IDisposable)host).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: you got it ;) little more concentration when developing is appreciated

Comment: Ugh, that was it. The concentration was there, it was just directed at all the wrong places. Stupid stupid. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A good primer is [Configuring Services Using Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms733932.aspx).

The name attribute on the service element must be the fully qualified name of the type implementing the service.

The contract attribute on the endpoint element must be the fully qualified name of the interface that the service implements.

If these two criteria are met, then the ServiceHost should find and apply the configuration specified in the app config.

An easy way to get started if you are new to WCF is to use the WCF service configuration editor, available from the tools menu of Visual Studio.